# Split firebase.json configuration into two different projects

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-tools

I have a working firebase project where I have a react project + cloud functions in it and I want to move all my functions into a different project (different repository), my problem is that I'm rewriting the hosting url to map the cloud functions like this

```
   "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/fns/cohorts/*/progress",
        "function": "cohortProgress"
      },
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
```

So I'm not sure how to split this firebase.json into two. One for the functions + hosting rewrites and other for the hosting only.

My guessing is that this two files are going to override one and another instead of merging.

Another idea I had was to use git submodules to manage only one file from this two different repositories but I'm not sure

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you find a satisfying solution for this?

Comment: I end up creating two different projects one for my react project and one for the api functions.